# What is the correct spelling of two fold?

Tags: orthography

Two fold, twofold, or two-fold: which one is the best option?

Comment: What do dictionaries show it as?

Comment: I found all three versions.

Comment: Research is always good — it **needs to be included in the question.** But we have a canonical answer. If that answer does not answer this question, please [edit it](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/528075/edit) to explain the particular difficulty.